# Highlight.js removing line breaks from core/code block after update

Tags: gutenberg-blocks, highlight.js

I am running highlight.js in the WordPress block editor and set highlight.js to run when core/code block is updated. The core/code block natively uses `<br data-rich-text-line-break="true">` for it's line breaks. But when highlight.js runs it removes the line breaks.

**Before:**

[image]

[image]

**After:**

[image]

[image]

I tried using the highlight.js ignoreUnescapedHtML function:

```
//Define a custom function to exclude specific elements
hljs.configure({
ignoreUnescapedHTML: /<br\/?>/i, // Ignore <br> and <br/> tags
});
```

But could not get to work.
https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html